# JasperReports generated in a Servlet (GWT) does not appear

Tags: java, servlets, gwt, jasper-reports

I am developing an application in GWT, I am using the api to generate *JasperReports* reports, initially tried to make the generation via RPC, which returned to the client a string with the path of the pdf created, but that did not work, now I'm trying to generate report by a normal servlet, **but the report is generated, nothing appears on the screen, and no error is found in the browser console.**

Details:

- dev mode works perfectly.
- on localhost: 8080 works perfectly.

The error is when the application is published in an external *Tomcat*

Here are my code

**Servlet:**

```
public class RelatorioPacienteServiceImpl extends HttpServlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private ServletContext sc;

public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    super.init(config);
    sc = config.getServletContext();
}

@SuppressWarnings({ "unused", "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String id = req.getParameter("id");
    Map m = req.getParameterMap();

    Paciente paciente = new Paciente();
    File reportFile = null;
    String dir = sc.getRealPath(sc.getContextPath().replaceAll("\\\\", "/"));

    Map parameters = new LinkedHashMap();

    String path = dir + "/../reports/";// tomcat
    path = path.replaceAll("\\\\", "/");

    try {
        paciente = PacienteDAO.getPacientePorId(Integer.parseInt(id));

        List<Paciente> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(paciente);

          HashMap parametros = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();  
        parametros.put("cpf", NumberMask.formatCpf(paciente.getCpf()));
        parametros.put("telefone1",NumberMask.formatPhone(paciente.getTelefone1()));
        parametros.put("telefone2",NumberMask.formatPhone(paciente.getTelefone2()));
        parametros.put("telefoneResponsavel",NumberMask.formatPhone(paciente.getTelefoneResponsavel()));
        parametros.put("dataNascimento",StringUtil.formatDate(paciente.getDataNascimento()));
        switch (paciente.getEtnia()) {
        case EtniaProps.BRANCA:
            parametros.put("etnia","Branco");
            break;
        case EtniaProps.INDIGENA:
            parametros.put("etnia","Indigena");
            break;
        case EtniaProps.PARDA:
            parametros.put("etnia","Parda");
            break;
        case EtniaProps.PRETA:
            parametros.put("etnia","Preta");
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        reportFile = new File(path + "report_paciente.jasper");

        byte[] bytes = null;

        JRDataSource jrds = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(list);

        try {
            bytes = JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(reportFile.getPath(), parametros, jrds);
        } catch (JRException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Erro ao gerar o relatório " + ex.getMessage());
        }

        if (!list.isEmpty()) {
            if (bytes != null && bytes.length > 0) {
                resp.setContentType("application/pdf");
                resp.setContentLength(bytes.length);
                ServletOutputStream outputStream = resp.getOutputStream();
                outputStream.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();

            }
        } else {
            resp.setContentType("text/html");
            ServletOutputStream outputStream = resp.getOutputStream();
            String mensagem = "<html>" + "<head>" + "<meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" charset=\"UTF-8\" content=\"text/html\">"
                    + "<title>Incor lages</title>" + "</head>" + "<body>"
                    + "<br><br><br><br><h1>Documento sem paginas" + "</body>" + "</html>";
            outputStream.write(mensagem.getBytes(), 0, mensagem.getBytes().length);
            resp.setContentLength(mensagem.getBytes().length);
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Erro ao execura a query " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Calling servlet:

```
String url = GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "relatorioPacienteService?id=" + paciente.getId();
Window.open(url, "_blank", "");
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Can u print reportFile.getPath(). I doubt the path of .jasper file is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it would be even better If you can post your `.jrxml` file.

Based on the info available **(report is generated, but blank)**, I think following is the area of concern:

```
 paciente = PacienteDAO.getPacientePorId(Integer.parseInt(id));

 List<Paciente> list = new ArrayList<>();
 list.add(paciente);
```

Make sure `PacienteDAO.getPacientePorId(Integer.parseInt(id));` is actually returning a bean. Beacuse If it does not return anything or returns null, the data source you use i.e. `JRBeanCollectionDataSource`, will have no data and hence nothing would be displayed.

Comment: PacienteDAO.getPacientePorId (Integer.parseInt (id)); 
yes is returning an object 
I'm erring on the report path, but still could not hit him . And thanks to reply

Comment: Try printing your report path to see if it gives desired path.